# Required to Enter a Value in Entry in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms

In my Application there is an Multiple `Entry` and `Button`.

What I want is that the `Entry` shouldn't be empty and if they are, then `Button` won't work. e.g. just like required Attribute in HTML.

I asked some what similar question like this for [Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631606/required-to-select-atleast-one-item-from-picker-in-xamarin), but this solution didn't work on `Entry`.

**Code for Entry & Button in Views**

```
<Entry
    Text="{Binding Email}"
    Keyboard="Email"
    ReturnType="Done"
    Placeholder="Enter Email">
</Entry>

<Entry
    Text="{Binding Password}"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    IsPassword="true"
    ReturnType="Done"
    Placeholder="Enter Password">
</Entry>

<Button
    Text="Submit"
    Command="{Binding FormDataButtonCommand}"/>
```

**Code for Entry and Button Binding in ViewModel.cs**

```
#region Bindable Command
public ICommand FormDataButtonCommand => new Command(async () => await FormDataButton(default, default));
#endregion

#region Bindable Properties
private string _Email;
public string Email
{
get => _Email;
set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Email, value);
}

private string _Password;
public string Password
{
get => _Password;
set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Password, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like https://www.reactiveui.net and use a lot `WhenAny...` `Observable` and all the cool reactive stuff

But as @Miamy said the command will be disable that way, but If you want to change the color or style, I'll do it this way

```
<Entry
    Text="{Binding Email}"
    Keyboard="Email"
    ReturnType="Done"
    Placeholder="Enter Email">
</Entry>

<Entry
    Text="{Binding Password}"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    IsPassword="true"
    ReturnType="Done"
    Placeholder="Enter Password">
</Entry>

<Button
    Text="Submit"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}"
    Command="{Binding FormDataButtonCommand}"/>
```

```
private string _Email;
public string Email
{
 get => _Email;
 set {
    IsButtonEnabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password);
    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Email, value);
  }
}

private string _Password;
public string Password
{
 get => _Password;
 set {
    IsButtonEnabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email);
  this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Password, value);
  }
}

private bool _IsButtonEnabled;
public bool IsButtonEnabled
{
 get => _IsButtonEnabled;
 set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _IsButtonEnabled, value);
}
```

Not a fan of doing it this way, but It's the simpler way... IMO

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to have `IsButtonEnabled` setter, this property can have a getter only. In this case `IsButtonEnabled` should be raised in `Email` and `Password` setters.

Comment: Fixed the `Email` `setter`

Comment: @Miamy, yes we could only use the `getter` and raised in the `Email` and `Password` setters, in order to be used as "`private`" and not the `Binding` `TwoWay`, but I think this way is sort of more readable or `property` user friendly :)

Comment: @jjchiw, in this case it should be better to have `IsButtonEnabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email);` in a single place and call it from all setters we need (in the future we could need to check first/lastname, phone etc.)

Comment: @jjchiw hi, I'm stuck in this problem, can u please have a look at it, it will be very nice of you :) => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495079/nullreferenceexception-on-page-navigation-in-c-sharp

Comment: What is the implementation of RaiseAndSetIfChanged as its not a recognised function

Comment: `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` is from  https://www.reactiveui.net it's like `INotificationChanged` - `OnPropertyChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

`ICommand` constructor cat take second parameter [CanExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute?view=netcore-3.1). You should use it for enabling/disabling a command:

```
public ICommand FormDataButtonCommand { get; set; } 
...
FormDataButtonCommand = new Command(FormDataButton, CanFormData); // in ctor

public bool CanFormData(object obj)
{
     return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password);
}


private async void FormDataButton(object obj)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: on `async () => await FormDataButton(default, default)` return the error `CS1593: Delegate 'Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments.`

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't compile or it doesn't work as planned?

Comment: didn't compiled.. because as u said to put the `FormDataButtonCommand = new Command(FormDataButton, CanFormData);` in constructor, I did it.. and it mark it as red..

Comment: So what  is an error you got? This snippet should work, I used it many times, and in xamarin too :)

Comment: In Constructor I wrote `FormDataButtonCommand = new Command(FormDataButton(default, default), CanFormData);` and it says that `CS503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Action<object>'`

Comment: `public async Task FormDataButton(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }`

Comment: Please use a syntax I wrote in the answer, it should work. You still can make command handler `async` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Multi-Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding)

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <local:AnyNullValueCheckConverter x:Key="AnyNullValueCheckConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Button>
   <Button.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AnyNullValueCheckConverter}">
          <Binding Path="Email" />
          <Binding Path="Password" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

Converter

```
public class AnyNullValueCheckConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (value is string str && string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can do it for other values e.g. Button.TextColor instead of false return Color.Gray and instead of true return Color.Black . Something like this.